# Drag and move a graph line with mouse in matplotlib of python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce an interactive graph in python's matplotlib. I have two sets of data, one is drawn as scatter plot and other is line plot. My minimal code is as follows.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = np.array([(0.310, -0.687), (0.407, -0.355), (0.455, -0.142), (0.504, 0.061), (0.552, 0.238), 
                  (0.601,  0.380), (0.698,  0.549), (0.746,  0.581), (0.795, 0.587), (0.859, 0.567), 
                  (0.956,  0.511), (1.053,  0.473), (1.150,  0.489), (1.199, 0.523), (1.296, 0.640), 
                  (1.393,  0.812), (1.490,  0.981), (1.587,  1.189), (1.684, 1.386), (1.781, 1.572), 
                  (1.878, 1.766)])

obser = np.array([(0.212, -0.114), (0.199, 0.017), (0.259, 0.020), (0.199, 0.076), (0.297, 0.082), 
                  (0.735, 0.085), (0.641, 0.104), (0.791, 0.104), (0.681, 0.109), (0.606, 0.132), 
                  (0.262, 0.135), (0.813, 0.137), (0.334, 0.157), (0.565, 0.165), (0.647, 0.170), 
                  (0.876, 0.174), (0.746, 0.186), (0.509, 0.197), (0.398, 0.203), (0.693, 0.207), 
                  (0.829, 0.215), (0.299, 0.226), (0.585, 0.228), (0.549, 0.242), (0.430, 0.242), 
                  (0.637, 0.253), (0.511, 0.257), (0.918, 0.268), (0.813, 0.269), (0.746, 0.271), 
                  (0.336, 0.288), (0.449, 0.297), (0.398, 0.299), (0.783, 0.306), (0.578, 0.312), 
                  (0.871, 0.330), (0.515, 0.345), (0.468, 0.353), (0.818, 0.380), (0.936, 0.391), 
                  (0.889, 0.416), (0.876, 0.503), (1.027, 0.522), (1.040, 0.601), (0.965, 0.656), 
                  (1.130, 0.796), (1.224, 0.845), (1.261, 0.964), (1.378, 1.149)])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0)

model2 = model - (0.37, 0.32)

ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.set_xlabel("BmV")
ax1.set_ylabel("UmB")
ax1.scatter(obser[:, 0], obser[:, 1], s=2, c="black")
ax1.plot(model[:, 0], model[:, 1], linewidth=1, c="red")
ax1.text(0.7, 0.96, 'Before', verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left', 
    transform = ax1.transAxes, color = 'black', fontsize=12)

ax2.invert_yaxis()
ax2.set_xlabel("BmV")
ax2.set_ylabel("UmB")
ax2.scatter(obser[:, 0], obser[:, 1], s=2, c="black")
ax2.plot(model2[:, 0], model2[:, 1], linewidth=1, c="red")
ax2.text(0.8, 0.96, 'After', verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left', 
    transform = ax2.transAxes, color = 'black', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

I want to drag and move the red line plot with mouse from "before" location to "after" location.

How can we do that?

[Before and After case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffk96.jpg)

Comment: [Two](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/path_editor.html#sphx-glr-gallery-event-handling-path-editor-py) [examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html#sphx-glr-gallery-event-handling-poly-editor-py) from the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: I know these examples, you can only drag and move JUST ONE POINT at a time. I want to drag & move whole line at once, not points of it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't have time to provide a full answer here. The point is, once you understood how those examples work, it will be easy to move just anything you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my working example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MoveGraphLine(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, graf, obj, eubv):
        self.ax = ax
        self.figcanvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.graf = graf
        self.obj = obj
        self.kayma = 0.0
        self.ebv, self.eub = eubv
        self.moved = None
        self.point = None
        self.pressed = False
        self.start = False

        self.figcanvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.mouse_press)
        self.figcanvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.mouse_release)
        self.figcanvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.mouse_move)

    def mouse_release(self, event):
        if self.ax.get_navigate_mode()!= None: return
        if not event.inaxes: return
        if event.inaxes != self.ax: return
        if self.pressed: 
            self.pressed = False
            self.start = False
            self.point = None
            self.ebv -= self.kayma
            self.obj = self.moved
            return

    def mouse_press(self, event):
        if self.ax.get_navigate_mode()!= None: return
        if not event.inaxes: return
        if event.inaxes != self.ax: return
        if self.start: return
        self.point = event.xdata
        self.pressed = True

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        if self.ax.get_navigate_mode()!= None: return
        if not event.inaxes: return
        if event.inaxes != self.ax: return
        if not self.pressed: return
        self.start = True

        self.kayma = self.point - event.xdata
        keub = 0.72 * self.kayma + 0.025 * self.kayma**2
        self.moved = self.obj - [self.kayma, keub]
        mvdx, mvdy = self.moved[:, 0], self.moved[:, 1]

        self.graf.remove()
        self.graf, = self.ax.plot(mvdx, mvdy, linewidth=1.1, c="b")

        self.figcanvas.draw()


model = np.array([(0.310, -0.687), (0.407, -0.355), (0.455, -0.142), (0.504, 0.061), (0.552, 0.238), 
                  (0.601,  0.380), (0.698,  0.549), (0.746,  0.581), (0.795, 0.587), (0.859, 0.567), 
                  (0.956,  0.511), (1.053,  0.473), (1.150,  0.489), (1.199, 0.523), (1.296, 0.640), 
                  (1.393,  0.812), (1.490,  0.981), (1.587,  1.189), (1.684, 1.386), (1.781, 1.572), 
                  (1.878, 1.766)])

obser = np.array([(0.212, -0.114), (0.199, 0.017), (0.259, 0.020), (0.199, 0.076), (0.297, 0.082), 
                  (0.735, 0.085), (0.641, 0.104), (0.791, 0.104), (0.681, 0.109), (0.606, 0.132), 
                  (0.262, 0.135), (0.813, 0.137), (0.334, 0.157), (0.565, 0.165), (0.647, 0.170), 
                  (0.876, 0.174), (0.746, 0.186), (0.509, 0.197), (0.398, 0.203), (0.693, 0.207), 
                  (0.829, 0.215), (0.299, 0.226), (0.585, 0.228), (0.549, 0.242), (0.430, 0.242), 
                  (0.637, 0.253), (0.511, 0.257), (0.918, 0.268), (0.813, 0.269), (0.746, 0.271), 
                  (0.336, 0.288), (0.449, 0.297), (0.398, 0.299), (0.783, 0.306), (0.578, 0.312), 
                  (0.871, 0.330), (0.515, 0.345), (0.468, 0.353), (0.818, 0.380), (0.936, 0.391), 
                  (0.889, 0.416), (0.876, 0.503), (1.027, 0.522), (1.040, 0.601), (0.965, 0.656), 
                  (1.130, 0.796), (1.224, 0.845), (1.261, 0.964), (1.378, 1.149)])


obv, oub =obser[:, 0], obser[:, 1]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5.31,6.79))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.14, bottom=0.08, right=0.95, top=0.97, wspace=0, hspace=0)

shift = (model.mean(axis=0) - obser.mean(axis=0))
sebv = shift[0]
seub = 0.72 * sebv + 0.025 * sebv**2

ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.set_xlabel("BmV")
ax1.set_ylabel("UmB")
ax1.set_ylim(2, -1)
ax1.set_xlim(-0.5, 2)
ax1.scatter(obv, oub, s=2, c="k")
gmdl, = ax1.plot(model[:, 0], model[:, 1], linewidth=1.1, c="b")

moveline = MoveGraphLine(ax1, gmdl, model, (sebv, seub))

plt.show()
```